# Unable to get the filelist using STD.File.RemoteDirectory

Tags: hpcc-ecl

We are trying to use a unix machine as landing zone for reading files into an HPCC Thor environment. Initially we would get the error

> System error: -1: Failed to connect (setting host down) to dafilesrv/daliservix on XX.XXX.XX.XX:7100

Then we got dafilesrv installed on the landing zone and started it. We also ensured if there are no firewall restriction between the two systems.

Now, when I try to read files from the landing zone, I do not get the above error. But, I do not get the filelist. The output from the following command is blank:

```
Filelist := STD.File.RemoteDirectory('XX.XXX.XX.XX','<file path>','*.csv');
output(Filelist);
```

is there configuration / setting we should be considering so that HPCC is able to get the list of files from the unix machine.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague (one of the platform developers) just tested this scenario between two Ubuntu VMs and was successfully able to get the file list. He did note to me that "I received empty result (without error) if the remote directory path wasn't correct (it was relative or contained typo)."

So I suggest that it is most likely that your remote directory path isn't correct.

HTH,

Richard

Comment: Thank you Richard for the response. The directory path is correct, I verified the path. Could it be because of some user / group related settings on the Unix box from where I am trying to read the files ?

Comment: "it is not configured / added as landing zone to the HPCC environment" -- so, if you want to use it as an LZ, why not just configure it as such? It could also be due to user/group settings, butI am no expert on Unix

Comment: Thanks Richard, the issue got resolved. The problem was with the hpcc user not configured. Once we configured the hpcc user on the unix server, I was able to get the files from the unix server.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Landing Zone Page]

The ECL Watch Landing Zone page can identify your proper *machineIP* and *dir* using the image above. And then:

`output(STD.File.RemoteDirectory('10.173.2xx.x','/mnt/disk1/var/lib/HPCCSystems/dropzone','*.csv'));`

Works for me! (I masked my IP address for security)

Comment: Thanks Bob for the response. Yes, the code works for me when I read from an existing environment (Unix box). But this Unix box we are trying to use for the first time to serve as the data source for HPCC and also it is not configured / added as landing zone to the HPCC environment. Could it be because of some user / group related settings on the Unix box from where I am trying to read the files ?

Comment: I am checking with the HPCC Operations team, but my best educated guess is that you need to add the Landing Zone to the HPCC Environment Configuration to be able to "see" it from the cluster.

Comment: Thanks Bob, the issue got resolved. The problem was with the hpcc user not configured. Once we configured the hpcc user on the unix server, I was able to get the files from the unix server.